# let $\mathbb{I}$ be a interval and $x \in \mathbb{I}$ Now Find range $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> let $\mathbb{I}$ be a interval and $x \in \mathbb{I}$ Now Find range $\frac{1}{x}$

---

For Ex :

Let $x\in [2,3)$ Then $\frac{1}{x}\in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]$

Let $x\in [-4,-2)$ Then $\frac{1}{x}\in (\frac{-1}{2},\frac{-1}{4}]$

Now Generally what ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the graph of $ y = \frac{1}{x}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then just calculate $1/x$ for the extreme points of $\mathbb{I}$ and write the solution correspondingly.

Comment: You have to be carefull if $0\in \mathbb{I}$.

Comment: That's why a graph is ideal.